# How to compile typescript without commenting out script tag in visual studio

Tags: visual-studio-2012, typescript

I need some script tag like  in the compiled JavaScript file. Is there any way I can compile typescript file with script tag? In visual studio 2012/2013, the typescript file can be compiled successfully after I comment out all the script tags.

Comment: Do you have an example, screenshot, or error message? I've never had a problem compiling TypeScript, whether or not they were referenced in a script element.

Answer (score 2):

> I need some script tag like in the compiled JavaScript file. Is there any way I can compile typescript file with script tag?

You can use something like this : https://github.com/niutech/typescript-compile that lets you use TypeScript directly :

```
<script type="text/typescript">
    ...
</script>
```

But I highly recommend against it. You should compile the TS to JS and reference the JS with a script tag